# How to filter students whose marks are greater than 80 at least in 2 subjects using java stream API?

Tags: java, java-stream

```
public class Student {

    private int stud_id;
    private String stud_name;
    private List<Integer> marks;
}    
public class Demo{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Student> ls=new ArrayList<>();
        ls.add(new Student(1,"Prasad",Arrays.asList(20,30,40,60)));
        ls.add(new Student(2,"Pratiksha",Arrays.asList(20,30,80,90)));
        ls.add(new Student(3,"Prasanthi",Arrays.asList(20,30,10,90)));
        //required code
        }
    }
```

Student class has id name and list of students. We have list of students now How can we filter out  the students who are having marks > 80 at least in 2 subjects?

Comment: Don't expect others to do homework for you. Try to solve it yourself and in case you are stuck on anything specific, then you may ask for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Stream#filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) along with [`Stream#count`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count--).

```java
List<Student> result = ls.stream().filter(s->s.getMarks()
           .stream().filter(m->m>=80).count() >= 2).collect(Collectors.toList());
```